# vista proporcional a diagrama de punto leaflet, openlayers

Tags: geolocalización, openlayers, geocodificación, leaflet

Estoy realizando un mapa de punto con leaflet, y al principio tengo que definir la vista junto con la escala;

```
     var map = L.map('map').
     setView([41.66, -4.72],
     5);
```

Sucede que después tengo un diagrama de puntos que se generaran automáticamente, con diferentes coordenadas, me gustaría si la vista pudiese generar coordenadas que abarcasen los diagramas de puntos a una escala proporcional.

Comment: No edito tu pregunta porque no estoy seguro de entenderla al 100% pero creo que la única etiqueta necesaria sería `leaflet` y que el título debería ser "Cómo hacer para que el mapa de leaflet englobe automáticamente todos los puntos"

Comment: Alguien con suficiente reputación debería crear una nueva etiqueta [leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/leaflet/info) y eliminar las que aparecen en este post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu capa de puntos es un geojson, la forma más sencilla es preguntar a esa capa cual es su [bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) con [getBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#featuregroup-getbounds), es decir, el rectángulo o caja más pequeño que engloba a todas las geometrías. Y luego setear ese bounding box en el mapa con [fitBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-fitbounds).

```
let geojsonData = null; // el geojson que representa tus puntos
let myLayer = L.geoJSON(geojsonData).addTo(map);
let bounds = myLayer.getBounds();
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

En ocasiones al usar fitBounds el mapa puede quedar demasiado ajustado a la capa y quieres darle un poco de padding, es decir, dejar más espacio entre las geometrías y los márgenes. Puedes hacerlo con las opciones de [fitBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#fitbounds-options), o ejecutando el método [pad](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#latlngbounds-pad) sobre `bounds`

Comment: muchas graacias !